# Android Motion Layout - Observe End of transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout, androidx, android-motionlayout

When using motion layout, I built a simple motion scene which changes a cricle from width/height of 100dp to 1000dp with a duration of 2000ms. 
Now I want to know programmatically when the animation is finsihed (Observer/Listener?)

I didn't found any built-in features or blog posts which are solving this problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

here some tricky way using transition listener

or use [Link](https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/a7371683c224464bf6bda5a25491aee0)

and modify on it as you need

Comment: where is your motionLayout.awaitTransitionComplete(...) method?

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/complex-ui-animations-on-android-featuring-motionlayout-aa82d83b8660